# Can I create custom reports with custom dimension drill downs in GA4?

Tags: reporting, google-analytics-4, custom-dimensions

I am upgrading to new GA4. I want to create a new custom reports in GA4 like the ones I created in universal analytics (UA). In old analytics, when I create new custom reports, I am able to add my custom dimensions in drill-down format like this:

[image: GA UA screenshot of custom report creation]

I want to create a same custom report in GA4 but I am not able to add my custom dimension in drill-down format like in the old version.
Is there any way to create custom report with custom dimensions like old Google analytics?

Comment: GA4 custom reports are somewhat lacking. Can't find a way to build custom drilldown reports. Cannot share your reports for others outside your organisation to use. 